# GEE Error - unable to transform geometry to pixel grid

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to convert a feature collection to an image. I can do it and add it to the map without an error, but when I export it, I get the following error:

Error: Unable to transform geometry to pixel grid. (Error code: 3)

[Here's the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2d73765526e1ea7d4645e038ef4e4d89):

```
var distinctClassNames = ee.List(therm.aggregate_array('TKThLP')).distinct();
    
var distinctClassCodes= ee.List ([1,2,3,4,5,null])

var lookup = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(distinctClassNames, distinctClassCodes);


var ice = therm.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['TKThLP']))
      function addNameCode(feature) {
          var thisClassName = feature.get('TKThLP');
          return feature.set('Thermokarst', lookup.get(thisClassName))}

 var ftCol = ice.map(addNameCode);

// delete emptry geometry
var bounded = ftCol.geometry().bounds();
var finalfts = ftCol.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(bounded))


var ThermImg = finalfts
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['Thermokarst']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['Thermokarst'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
}).rename("permafrost");


var arcticbounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([180,50,-180,80],null,false);


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ThermImg,
  folder: 'final_tifs',
  description: 'thermokarst_500m',
  scale: 463.3127165275,
  crs: "SR-ORG:6974",
  region: arcticbounds,
  maxPixels: 1E12
});
```

Comment: first line should be:
var therm = imported table (see link)